# Scope -- how to evaluate an object in parent environment if local var with same name exists?

Tags: r, environment-variables

If I have two nested environments using the same variable name, how would I grab the value of the outer environment?

I am having difficulty figuring out the correct way to implement this.  I have tried a few variations of `parent.frame(x)` and `sys.frame(x)` inside eval. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

EXAMPLE:

```
outerFunc <- function() { 
  obj <- "Outer Object"
  innerFunc()
}

innerFunc <- function() {
  # A local variable with same name is created
  obj <- "Inner Object"

  # would like to grab the value of obj from the outer environment
  obj.callingFunc <- eval(obj, envir=sys.frame(-1))

  cat(obj.callingFunc)  # gives "Inner Object" instead of "Outer Object"
} 

> outerFunc()
Inner Object
```

*The obvious solutions (Pass `obj` explicitly. Use a different variable name, etc) are not available to me in this specific case.*

---

### EDIT

examining @GregSnow's and @Dwin's answers below

```
  # THESE WORK
  eval(quote(obj), envir=parent.frame()) # equivalent to evalq(obj, envir=parent.frame())
  get("obj", envir=parent.frame())

  # THESE DO *NOT* WORK
  eval("obj", envir=parent.frame()) 
  get(quote(obj), envir=parent.frame())
```

Any thoughts as to the effects of quoting in `get()` vs `eval()`?

---

Comment: Can you explain why the obvious solutions aren't available?  It feels like you're asking us a question about a particular way to solve your real problem, rather than telling us your real problem.  Perhaps there's a better way altogether.

Comment: @Aaron, what I am hoping to accomplish is to learn how to work with variables in different environments. My comment at the end was to avoid the temptation of offering work-arounds that offered the same end-result but not the knowledge :)  The functions above are simply to test and learn and not representative of any problem at hand.

Comment: Ricardo: I applaud your efforts. The inner working of R evaluation is is an area that few people understand (and I do not include myself in the group that understands it well.)  I'm guessing there may be some number between fifty and two hundred that do understand it well.

Comment: On quoting: `get` takes strings as input, `eval` takes calls or expressions.  Supplying the wrong input to a function is unlikely to make it work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
outerFunc <- function() { 
  obj <- "Outer Object"
  innerFunc()
}

innerFunc <- function() {
  # A local variable with same name is created
  obj <- "Inner Object"

  # would like to grab the value of obj from the outer environment
  cat( get('obj', envir=parent.frame()) )

   } 

 outerFunc()
#Outer Object
```

Could have also used: `eval(quote(obj), envir=sys.frame(-1))`. It becomes clear that the meaning of quote(expr) is different than than of "expr".  The `get` function is "expecting" (or perhaps more accurately is designed) to receive character values, whereas `eval` is expecting calls and expressions, i.e "language" objects. There is sort of a semi-permeable membrane between data and language in R and `get` is one of the membrane channels through which you can pass character valued objects to language domain.

Comment: thanks as always for the detailed response(s).  +1 for pointing me towards language objects, which helps to clarify the return value of `quote()`

Comment: I think using "calling" environment instead of "outer" environment would be helpful in the comment - you need to distinguish between lexical scoping (i.e. how the functions were defined) from dynamic scoping (how the functions were called). Outer environment is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `eval` to `evalq` or otherwise quote `obj` in the call to eval.  As is obj is being evaluated before it is given to `eval` so it has the inner value, quoting it says pass the expression (not the value) to `eval` to be evaluated.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, by quoting I meant something like `eval(quote(obj), ...`.  I should have been more specific.